# How do I make Maps and lambdas work with a matrix in python 3.4?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I often avoid me to write posts like this but I'm new in python 3.4 and I need a help with this code.

Suppose we have the following list:

```
v = [ [ x, y ] for x in ['a','b','c'] for y in range(1,5) ]
```

It results a list of lists: [ ['a', '1'], ['a','2'], ... ]

Now I'd want to join those string. I've tried the following:

```
p = map(lambda (x, y): ''.join(x,y), v)
```

It didn't work.

The error:

```
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

I've tried to look up in the documentation But I coudn't solve my problem though.

Does someone have some idea?

Comment: Did you get an exception? How didn't it work?

Comment: "it didn't work" - what didn't work? syntax error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it

Comment: The signature of `str.join`: `S.join(iterable) -> str`

Comment: `lambda (x, y): ''.join(x,y)` isn't valid Python 3. Are you sure that's the version you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)), v))
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

This executes the function `lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x))` for each element in `v`. An element in `v` is a list with one string and one integer as values. This means `x`, as received by the `lambda` function, is a list with those two values.

We then need to ensure all values in that list are strings before passing them to `join()`. This means we'll call `map(str, x)` to turn all values in the sublist `x` into strings (`['a', 1]` becomes `['a', '1']`). We can then join them by passing the result of that to `''.join(...)` (`['a', '1']` becomes `['a1']`). This is done for each list in `v` so this gives us the desired result.

The result of `map` is a so-called `mapobject` in Python 3.x so we wrapped everything in a `list()` call to end up with a list.

Also, a list comprehension is arguably more readable here:

```
>>> [x[0] + str(x[1]) for x in v]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Comment: It worked.But I can't understand your first solution.

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte: I'll expand my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. `lambda (x, y): ''.join(x,y)` isn't legal Python 3. Iterable unpacking of arguments was removed. *If you actually ran the code you showed on the version you mentioned, you would have gotten a syntax error, not the error you showed.*
2. If you did indeed have a list as you describe, not the one you actually made, you would need to give `str.join` one iterable argument, not 2 arguments, so `lambda (x, y): ''.join([x,y])` (which is similar to the code you showed but not legal Python 3) or, more simply, `lambda x_y: ''.join(x_y)`
3. That won't work for you, though, because `str.join` takes an iterable of strings, and the resulting list of lists in your case is  `[ ['a', 1], ['a',2], ... ]`, not `[ ['a', '1'], ['a','2'], ... ]`. You can't join a string and a number this way. (Which is fine, since `str.join` isn't even the right tool for the job.)
4. **Using `map`+`lambda` is *always* silly.** Just use a generator expression in all situations you might use `map`+`lambda`

See the following examples (I used list comprehensions instead of generator expressions so we'd get useful reprs):

```
py> v = [ [ x, y ] for x in ['a','b','c'] for y in range(1,5) ]
py> [''.join([let, num]) for let, num in v]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found
py> ['{}{}'.format(let, num) for let, num in v]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a set amount of elements to join you can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
print(list(map(lambda x: "{}{}".format(*x) , v)))  

['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

You can also do it for any amount of elements using `"{}" * len(x)`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: ("{}" * len(x)).format(*x) , v)))
```

`*x` unpacks the sequence, `"{}" * len(x)` creates a `{}` for each element in each sublist.

Or unpack in a list comp:

```
print([ "{}{}".format(*x) for x in v])
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mike that `map(lambda` is silly. In this case, `'{}{}'.format` pretty much does the job your lambda is supposed to do, so you can use that instead:

```
starmap('{}{}'.format, v)
```

That uses [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap). If you want to use `map`, you can do it like this:

```
map('{}{}'.format, *zip(*v))
```

But really I'd just do

```
(c + str(n) for c, n in v)
```

---

Edit: A comparison of map+lambda vs generator expression, showing that the latter is shorter, clearer, more flexible (unpacking), and faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> r = range(10000000)
>>> timeit(lambda: sum(map(lambda xy: xy[0]+xy[1], zip(r, r))), number=1)
7.221420832748007
>>> timeit(lambda: sum(x+y for x, y in zip(r, r)), number=1)
5.192609298897533

>>> timeit(lambda: sum(map(lambda x: 2*x, r)), number=1)
5.870139625224283
>>> timeit(lambda: sum(2*x for x in r), number=1)
4.4056527464802

>>> r = range(10)
>>> timeit(lambda: sum(map(lambda xy: xy[0]+xy[1], zip(r, r))), number=1000000)
7.047922363577214
>>> timeit(lambda: sum(x+y for x, y in zip(r, r)), number=1000000)
4.78059718055448
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why using map(lamba is silly. I came from R and it's very usual write lines like that there.

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte Like Mike said: "Just use a generator expression" instead. See the "Edit:" part of my answer that I just added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another list comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join((x, str(y))) for x, y in v]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

If you don't need `v`, you can do in the first list comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join((x, str(y))) for x in ['a','b','c'] for y in range(1,5)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```