# Compressing function within comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am taking `l=['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']` as input and I am converting it into `l=[1,2,3,'rt4','rt5']` with the following code:

```
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

l=['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
l=[int(l[i]) if RepresentsInt(l[i]) else l[i] for i in range(0,len(l))]
```

Can I improve above code using a comprehension?

Comment: You can't use exception handling in an expression (a list comprehension is an expression and can only contain other expressions), so what you want is *not possible*. You could limit yourself to strings with only digits in them and use `str.isdigit()`, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your `RepresentsInt` function to actually return the integer (if possible) which would make this much easier:

```
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Then the code to transform the list could be written as (using a `for item in l` loop is probably better than iterating over the indices):

```
>>> l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
>>> [RepresentsInt(item) for item in l]
[1, 2, 3, 'rt4', 'rt5']
```

Or if you want that as a reusable pattern you still need a helper function (I chose a decorator-like approach here) because you can't use `try` and/or `except`s in comprehensions:

```
def try_to_apply_func(func, exception):
    def newfunc(value):
        try:
            return func(value)
        except exception:
            return value
    return newfunc

>>> to_int_if_possible = try_to_apply_func(int, ValueError)
>>> [to_int_if_possible(item) for item in l]  
[1, 2, 3, 'rt4', 'rt5']

>>> to_float_if_possible = try_to_apply_func(float, ValueError)
>>> [to_float_if_possible(item) for item in l]  
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 'rt4', 'rt5']
```

Answer (score 3):

It's really unclear what you want, but maybe something like :

```
>>> l=['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
>>> l=[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in l]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 'rt4', 'rt5']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe (though I could ultimately be wrong) that there is a cleaner and neater way to achieve this. One solution would be to create an integer parsing `lambda` expression, such as the following, but I think your current solution is much neater and more robust.

```
>>> l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
>>> l = list(map(lambda s : (s.isdigit() or (s[0] == '-' and s[1:].isdigit())) and int(s) or s, l))
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 'rt4', 'rt5']
```

This won't correctly catch strings such as `'1.0'` or `'  1'`, but it should just about do what you want in two lines.

Comment: Why would you ever do `list(map(lambda s :` instead of a list comprehension? Also, your code doesn't work, you're missing a `)`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Also I've somehow taken to using the `map(` syntax quite commonly and just applied it here without really thinking. Tomatoes, tomatoes I guess.

Comment: Except your tomatoes are longer and slower :-)

Comment: Yes. For example `timeit('[x for x in a]', 'a = [0] * 100')` takes me about 2.5 seconds and `timeit('list(map(lambda x: x, a))', 'a = [0] * 100')` takes me about 7.9 seconds. More thoughts in the second half [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413651/1672429) (although there it's map+lambda vs generator expression).

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware of that. I guess I'll have to start using list comprehension more, is there any advantage to using maps, over generators that you know of then?

Comment: Map alone is a different story. It's the map **+ lambda** combination that's usually bad (especially if you even need a `list(...)` around it). If you already have a function, then mapping it is good, e.g., `map(int, mystrings)`. And in Python 2, `map` accepts `None` as function and it maps for as long as its *longest* given iterable, both of which would take more code without `map`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for taking the time to fill in a gap in my understanding, much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get your desired result.

```
l = ['1','2','3','rt4','rt5']
l = [int(each) if each.isdigit() else each for each in l]
print l
```